# Как получить доступ к диску OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

Я решил получить доступ к своему диску, но я не понимаю как это сделать.
Клиент написан на C#, я зарегистрировал приложение на портале Azure AD, получил токен и хочу отправить запрос GET [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect_uri%7D). Вопрос: где и как брать, а может предварительно создать, заданного клиента, а также получить его client_secret...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я забыл тут написать, вдруг кому попадется.
В общем client_id это в Azure ИД приложения, секрет получаем также в Azure: заходим на сертификаты и секреты -> секреты клиента -> новый секрет клиента.
Я аутентифицировался без пользователя https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/graph/auth-v2-service и поэтому понадобился tenant(ИД каталога).
Ко всему надо иметь SPO лицензию(возможно можно как то бесплатно ее получить)